# Convert a column with floats and string in floats only

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 120 |
| 2 | 4 500 |
| 3 | 3 000 |

120 is considered as a number but 4500 and 3000 are considered as strings because of space. I think I have to check each cells of the dataframe if the cells is strings with space can be a digit with like is_digit then I convert it in int.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all spaces and pass to [`to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
df2 = df.apply(lambda s: pd.to_numeric(s.astype(str).str.replace(r'\s', '', regex=True),
                                       errors='coerce'))
```

output:

```
   A     B
0  1   120
1  2  4500
2  3  3000
```

used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3],
                   'B': [120, '4 500', '3 000']})
```

Comment: It removes completely 4500 and 3000 to replace it by NaN. And I need to keep the numbers.

Comment: can you provide your example dataframe as DataFrame constructor for clarity? `df.to_dict('list')`

Comment: Yes sure. `00:
nan
01:
'1\xa0117\xa0282'
02:
'0'
03:
nan
04:
nan
05:
'93'
06:
'120'
07:
nan
08:
nan
09:
'5'
10:
'0'
11:
nan
12:
nan
13:
'90'` The output of number 1 is 1 117 282 but I don't know this type.

Comment: OK, non standard space, see the update with a regex